What is this grid with diagonal lines called besides a "rule", "grid", "squares with 4 lines of symmetry"?
What is this grid with diagonal lines called? And not just 'rule', 'grid', or 'squares with 4 lines of symmetry'.


This is not about standard everyday English (and I taught maths to beyond A-Level). Mathematics.SE is the place to ask for such a subject-specific term.

The technical term is Tetrakis square tiling or Kisquadrille (Wikipedia).
More familiar generic terms (but less generic than "grid") might be mesh or lattice, although it's not a lattice in the mathematical sense.
